# Designing Services with different types of parameters java

Tags: java

I am working on designing a common `Service` interface for atleast 5 concrete implementations. Now all these services require different types of inputs. I thought of creating a `Param` class to hold parameters, so that interface could remain common. but then, for some implementations, some of the fields will be unused. I also thought of using `Map` to hold my params, but that is also not good(casts and if-elses everywhere). Also, I thought of doing was to create a class with Static methods `Service.responseAsPerFirstImplementation(p1, t1, i1)` and such. But, this way is not good coding. Please suggest how I should design between Modular design, flexibility vs variability of parameters?

EDIT:
Is below the good way of doing it?

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Services.response(new UserParam(1, new Date())));
        System.out.println(Services.response(new PatternParam("core")));
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want a common interface then?

Comment: So as not to expose the implementations to the client. I want to use the method where you get a `Service` instance from a `Services` class (to support instance caching etc.)

Comment: But why a *common* interface?

Comment: Ok. I got your point. Leave the common interface. How do you propose I should layout the things please?

Comment: Where do your parameters come from? Are they "generic" like HTTP request parameters or command-line parameters? What is the mapping logic between them and parameters of your services?

Comment: As of now they will come from simple Swing based UI's fields and selectors, but I want to build it to be easily pluggable into a web based project, where the params will come from HTTP requests.

Comment: One way I think could be to create different interface for each type and a common factory. Please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the core of the question is if your parameters come from some "generic", unstructured sourcelike HTTP request parameters or command line arguments  or some structured source - I would put a Swing form there as you know in advance which UI elements you have.

In case of "generic" parameters you have to convert these parameters into something your services can process. You can do this manually or with some library/framework. For instance, you can use annotations to describe how your HTTP request and its parameters map to your controllers/services/methods:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/trainRun")
public class TrainRunController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{year}/{month}/{day}/{trainNumber}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public TrainRun getTrainRun(@PathVariable Integer year, @PathVariable Integer month, @PathVariable Integer day,
                                @PathVariable String trainNumber) { ... }
}
```

Similarly with command-line parameters - you can use somethings like args4j to map CLI parameters into Java object first and then call your services appropriately.

Hope this helps.